# Calculating error and shunt resistor size for current sensing

Tags: current-measurement

I was going through TI training to choose what current shunt resistor to choose.

I wanted to monitor my yacht 12V power systems.

I have an INA3221 3 channel voltage/current sense board.

How do I calculate the correct shunt to use? There's a balance between wasting power and accuracy but I'm not sure where to draw that line. Obviously the least power use is best but how do I find that out?

There may be 150A out of the battery but the wind generator may be up to 10A to monitor. How do I make these calculations and also know the accuracy?

I tried their formula based on INA199. Gain of 50V/V. = 10mOhm shunt

[image]

The [inna3221 says gain is 1V/V](https://www.ti.com/product/INA3221). That would have a 1.2 Ohm resistor at 10 amps burning way too much power.

Should I be looking at something different on the datasheet or is this device incorrect?

Comment: Look for a high gain INA